# Why Midoriya said he remembered All for One's memories?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In manga chapter #194

> After dreaming about former One for All owners and having some dreams/memories of the original One for All, Midoriya tells All Might about this and when replying to something All Might said, Midoriya says "Yeah.. it was also technically All For One's memories.

Why Midoriya said he remembered All for One's memories? I understand him having One for All former owners memories, but All for One's ??

Comment: The one for all quirk is a  combination of 2 quirks, one of which was originally owned by all for one. My guess is that quirks passed on to other people could infact retain a bit of memories from the original owner.

Comment: Maybe he was referring to those bits where we see AFO gathering an army, though his brother technically was imprisoned then and didn't see that himself. I'm pretty sure none of what he saw was pure AFO memory, they were all related to the First in some way.